# Loop within tf.Session()

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my TensorFlow project I'd like to try different optimizers and ideally I'd loop over them, so I can compare the training in TensorBoard. I've extracted the optimization bit because that fails. I have something like this:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

eta = 0.1
num_epochs = 100

xv = tf.Variable(0.0)
sv = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

loss = xv * xv - 4.0 * xv + 5.0

optimizers = [tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(eta),
              tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(eta),
              tf.train.AdamOptimizer(eta)]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

summary_op = tf.summary.scalar('x', xv)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('log', graph=tf.get_default_graph())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for optimizer in optimizers:
      objective = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=sv)
      for epoch in range(num_epochs):
          _, step, result, summary = sess.run([objective, sv, xv, summary_op])
          writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=step)
          writer.flush()
      saver.save(sess, os.getcwd() + '/output')
      print(sess.run(xv))
```

It fails with `Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node Adagrad/update_Variable_2/ApplyAdagrad:
 Variable_2 (defined at <stdin>:1)`

Can something like this be done in TensorFlow or am I using the session wrong in that I'm trying to run the same thing from scratch several times within the same session without re-initializing the variables? I'm not sure how to achieve that though. I tried placing the loop outside of `tf.Session()` but that did not work either.

Comment: Try running the optimizer loop outside the session and clear the graph after every run.

Comment: That gives me `AssertionError: Do not use tf.reset_default_graph() to clear nested graphs. If you need a cleared graph, exit the nesting and create a new graph.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually only attach one optimizer to the same sets of variables.

When you call `optimizer.minimize(loss)`, tensorflow automatically choose the variables that affect loss to optimize. Calling 3 times `optimizer.minimize(loss)` on the same loss and call `session.run(...)` alternatively is not advisable.

If you hope to compare the 3 optimizer, it would be better use 3 scripts to test each optimizer separately.

Besides, you should call `optimizer.minimize(...)` for any optimizer only once because repeating call that function only adds new operations to the graph. The actual computing is performed when you call `session.run(...)`